# Error while using Blazor Singleton to pass values between pages

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I am passing data between Blazor pages  by registering a singleton service and injecting it as a dependency onto the pages or components that need.
I have added the below codes in my project to make it work:

AppData.cs in ServicesRouting folder

```
namespace Trade.FrontOffice.Client.ServicesRouting
{
    public class AppData
    {
        public string tradeID { get; set; }
        public string utpID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
services.AddScoped<Client.ServicesRouting.AppData>();
}
```

injected into my first razor page

```
@inject Client.ServicesRouting.AppData AppData
```

assigned some values to AppData

```
AppData.tradeID = tradeValue.tradeId;
AppData.utpID = tradeValue.utpid;
```

I am getting an error in browser console :
[image: error image from console]

Comment: Can you clarify your project type - you have used both Blazor Server and Blazor WebAssembly tags on your question, the you said you added the service in startup.cs and got errors in the browser console - it sounds like you are expecting services from the aspnetcore hosting project of a "Blazor WebAssembly Hosted" solution to magically appear in the WebAssembly client - is that right?

Comment: I have added AppData.cs in blazor client side, and registered class as service in Startup.cs which is in server side of the project. Following the below link for the routing magic to happen https://wellsb.com/csharp/aspnet/blazor-singleton-pass-data-between-pages/

Comment: I think i got my answer. as the AppData.cs is in client side and service registered in server side . AppData was not read or detected. I added services.AddScoped<Client.ServicesRouting.AppData>(); at Program.cs in client side & it works. Your question kinda made me think & make changes. Thanks +1

Comment: Yeah.. Remember that Client project know nothing about the server...